# Multiple dependent drop-down lists in google sheets without script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I work with G sheets in various contexts and this is a pretty frequent use case.
In this case, let's say the spreadsheet looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PAg2Gr2T1gUmqlbAJaJjMQ37yO_YI5sYz9WMY3Q1lEg/edit?usp=sharing

Continents in Column B, Countries in Column C. And then, on another sheet, a list of values that correspond with a given country. So what I want is in Column C to select from the list of continents, but in column D, select from the list of countries within that continent.

Col. B | Col. C | Col. D |

Paris | Europe | France|

I've reviewed questions going over how to do this with scripts, but can't seem to replicate it. I'm also wondering if there's a quick-and-dirty way to do this with formulas or by adding additional filtered tables.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Posts on this site should limit to a single question and it should be specific. Please edit the question to limit it to a single question (script or formula?) and show what you tried and where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

**You can use a script or a formula to accomplish a dependent drop-down list.**

### **Google Apps Script**

**Single dropdown menu:**

Create a dropdown list in cell `C6` of the `Data` sheet that takes values from the range `B3:B` in the `Values` sheet (column Region). Then copy the code below to the script editor and click on save. Every time you select a new item in the dropdown list in cell `C6`, a dependent dropdown list will appear/updated with a list of the corresponding countries in cell `D6`. See **Instructions** on how to setup and use this solution.

```
function onEdit(e){

    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const val = e.range.getValue();
    const val_not = e.range.getA1Notation();
    const vs = e.source.getSheetByName("Values");
    const opts = vs.getRange('B3:C' + vs.getLastRow()).getValues();
      
    if (val_not =='C6' && as.getName() == "Data"){
      
      const fopts = opts.filter(o=>o[0]==val)
      const droplist = fopts.map(o=>o[1]).sort().reverse().filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);   
      const cell = as.getRange('D6');
      const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(droplist).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
      cell.clearContent();
      cell.clearDataValidations();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  }
```

**Instructions:**

[image: dropdown gif]

---

**Multiple dropdown menus:**

The logic is exactly the same as before. The only modifications you have to do is to drag up/down the dropdown list in column `C` to the cells that you want to have a dropdown list and use this script instead:

```
function onEdit(e){

    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const val = e.range.getValue();  
    const row = e.range.getRow();
    const col = e.range.getColumn();
    
    const vs = e.source.getSheetByName("Values");
    const opts = vs.getRange('B3:C' + vs.getLastRow()).getValues();
      
    if (row > 2 && col == 3 && as.getName() == "Data"){
      
      const fopts = opts.filter(o=>o[0]==val)
      const droplist = fopts.map(o=>o[1]).sort().reverse().filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);   
      const cell = as.getRange(row,4);
      const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(droplist).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
      cell.clearContent();
      cell.clearDataValidations();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  }
```

[image]

---

### **Google Sheets Formula**

Instead of providing an explanation here which will make this post even longer than already is, I prefer to redirect you to a YouTube video that will help you figure out how to set up a dependent dropdown list using google sheet formulas:

[Google Sheets - Drop Down List, 2 Dependent Dropdown Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUM6s-hbX6w)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a link to the sheet you demo with here so we can see how everything is linked together (particularly the script and the sheet)

Comment: @youngrrrr hi! Unfortunately, I don't have the sheet anymore. But if you see the gif picture, I display the ranges of the values for the dropdown menu, as well as the main sheet and how I install everything. Let me know if you have any issues and I will help you of course.

Comment: Ah that is indeed unfortunate. I was hoping for a portable/modularized solution but it seems I just need to learn some Google scripting. Thank you though for this answer! It got me started on the right path :)

Comment: @youngrrrr consider upvoting the answer if it helped you towards the right direction :)

Comment: @Mario 

This script that you made worked very well, however, I identified 2 possible "problems":

1-When adding or removing a value in list2, the old cells (which had already been filled in), do not consider the new values in the list.
2-When pasting the same value filled in the same cell (to try to update the list of values2) the list starts to consider the new values. However, the value that was filled in is cleared automatically;
Do you see if there is any way to solve these problems? In the video below I demonstrate the problem:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wMxAYTAnsWmQpHiA6